# When it came time to

Tags: grammaticality, idioms

> When it came time to...

Is the phrase technically correct, or is it an exercise of artistic license?

Comment: It is an idiom.

Comment: I couldn't dissect how the parts of speech play out together.

Comment: Idioms (a) are widely used and accepted expressions, and (b) show either non-standard sense of words or non-standard grammar (or both). This is an extragrammatical idiom. Correctness is usage-driven, so as this expression is widely used and accepted, it's correct. 'Technically' is ill-defined in these areas, and one could argue that all idioms are artistic and stretch the boundaries of what is considered acceptable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phrase is perfectly valid. I have seen the phrase used mostly to convey some kind of a twist, as in:

> When it came time to vote, the senator
>   switched sides.

Answer (score 0):

Seems perfectly fine to me, though would benefit from more context. E.g.:

> When it came time to leave, she was ready.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't "When it was time to..." be better?

Answer (score 0):

I've found that "when the time came" is used more often than "when it came time". I personally have not found that either is incorrect so I suppose it just depends on the flow of your sentence and the context it is in.

Comment: Please [explain your answer](//english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), preferably with some supporting statements and [references](//english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). While opinions are valued, they are not of much help as answers.

Comment: @NVZ, the same could be said for other answers, too

Answer (score 0):

> When it came time to...

Is an abbreviation of "*When it [be]came time to...*." or "*When it became time for..."*, for the event to happen or occur.

It is a slightly archaic, formal or more poetic way of saying:  "When it was time..."